# Coldfusion: is it better to keep just the user_id in the session, or the whole user object?

Tags: session, coldfusion

I've got a cfc to handle the user object.  My question is: is it better to store just the user_id in the session and create the user object anew with each request?  Or is is better to store the whole user object in the session?

Here are my thoughts either way:

- If I store the whole object in the session:

  - There will be potentially less processor overhead
  - There will be potentially more memory overhead
  - all of the methods/functions are stored in the actual object, and new functions that I update in the cfc will not be available unless users logout and back in, or if I devise some way to make it refresh itself.
  - There could potentially be mutex or lock problems if I'm messing with the object via concurrent ajax calls
- If I store just the user_id in the session:

  - I'll have to create the user object with each page request (potentially more processor overhead)
  - There will be potentially less memory overhead
  - There won't be a chance for mutex/lock/race conditions since each request will have its own copy of the user object
  - Updates to the CFC model itself will be immediately recognized across the system and users wouldn't have to log out and back in

Is there a normal practice for this sort of thing?  Am I over-thinking it?

Comment: It depends...  If you are using ORM look into secondary cache for the user cfc.

Comment: @sam-farmer Using a home-grown ORM, which user.cfc inherits from. I'm assuming you're talking about CF9's built-in ORM, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't indicated whether you're using an ORM, so this is a general answer.

For typical applications, I recommend instantiating the user object into the session scope. There's a big downside to creating the object anew with each request that you didn't include in your list: changes to the user object's properties and state will not persist across requests unless you intend to flush the user object's state to your persistence layer (e.g. database) on every hit. That is likely to be a much more expensive operation than object instantiation, and it doesn't necessarily insulate you from the kinds of problems you're thinking about with respect to ajax calls, race conditions, etc -- it just transfers the manifestation of those problems to the persistence layer, where your object's data could be in an unpredictable state.

Since every new request would be an "implicit save", you would also have to design your "ephemeral" object to be able to persist itself regardless of whether it's in a valid state (imagine the case of a multi-page form that modifies some aspect of the user object).

For session-stored objects, your concerns about memory can be mitigated by careful design practices. For instance, if your user has many tasks, and each task has many items, it might be a bad idea to instantiate and compose all those objects into your user object (i.e., lazy loading would be a better approach than eager loading).

If you really must to be able to change your CFCs on the fly, you can achieve that goal even with session-stored objects. One way is to store a version flag in both the application and session. With each request, your app would compare those flags. When they differ, the app would run a session-reload routine that snapshots current properties, rebuilds the session-stored objects, and finally updates the session flag to match the application flag.

Comment: Your last edit (last paragraph) really helped make your case so far.

Comment: While all of the answers here were super-helpful, yours gave me the most helpful information for me to make a good decision.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

All of the CF apps I've written were targeted at high traffic levels and high availability, so we never had the luxury of being able to think about single-server practices.

So, in my experience, I always had to a) allow for multiple load-balanced servers, and b) avoid sticky-sessions on the load balancer for a number of reasons.  Therefore, we needed to, at the very least, have a server become part of a cluster on the fly and pick up mid-session traffic.

So, we always pulled "session" data from a shared datastore on every request.

My suggestion is to implement a **session facade**.

This affords you the option to change how you persist session data (like the user record) without changing the rest of your app.

You can choose, behind the scenes, to store everything in the session scope, load it up for every request, do a hybrid, use a key-value store, whatever.

You can choose whether to eager-load data, or lazy-load data, or any mix in between, and the rest of the app doesn't need to be aware of what you've done.

#### On Race Conditions

If you're concerned about race conditions then I would suggest using named locks around data commit and access.  This is another bonus of using a facade - your application code doesn't need to know about this, and you can choose to put locks around certain objects, as opposed to locking the whole session.

Comment: +1 Facade is a good suggestion; he'll certainly need abstraction if he's running a big app. This is one of those questions whose answers can really lead you down the rabbit hole. Holes. But in a good way.

Answer (score 2):

This is piggy-backing partially off Ken Redler's answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

The way we do it, and the way I prefer, is to store the user data in Session as a struct. Then on request start, our Auth Model creates the user object in the Request scope and overrides any default values with the Session data. There are a few advantages to this:

- Less hits to the database, less CPU
- Always run newest code without a complex custom system ensuring that
- Clustered environment friendly (complex objects in Session can't be clustered)
- Can add or remove properties without corruption (assuming your User object only updates dirty columns)

Also, if you're using CF9, one of the features they were really proud of is how much they optimized object instantiation. If you haven't, test it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

**It depends**.

If you have a lot of traffic - in the thousands of unique visitors per minute range - the memory overhead of storing your User.cfc in the session will eventually weigh you down. This can be easily overcome by throwing hardware at it (more memory for a while, eventually more servers and a hardware load balancer). Of course popularity is a good problem to have.

If you seem to have a CPU, network or other bottleneck in your database space, you may want to have the object cached in session memory so that you have fewer hits to the database.

Why do I mention these scenarios? You may be prematurely optimizing - don't fix a problem that you don't have. Don't optimize your memory, CPU and database access until those are, or soon will be, problems.

Now from an architectural best practice - not from an optimized "what's best for my processor" - well, I can only say: **It depends**.

Truthfully, neither way is wrong. If you are going to find yourself needing to check credentials against your database on every request, don't cache it. If you like the feel of an object in the session, then cache it. Because you know your own domain, you can probably go back and forth all day on why you should or should not cache the user object in the session. If it's going to make it easier, do it. If it's going to make it harder, don't.

I would just warn you against doing something incredibly convoluted or anything that is not immediately obvious to a developer looking at your application - the more you write, the more you have to maintain forever, the more your co-workers will associate your name with evil.

Finally, last note, if this is a vote - I say you cache it. It makes sense and always feels good to call session.user.hasRole("xyz") or the like.